# Download OSM data with QuickOSM and QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, overpass-api, quickosm

I've been using QuickOSM plugin for some time and I would like to create some model that allows me to automate OSM data dowload in order to make sure that I am always working with the most updated information.

My intention was to perform an overpass query on bbox defined by a custom name to look at nominatim and then save the output into a vector file and load it into QGIS in order to work with it. So, with that in mind I created the following very basic model (it's the first one I ever create -a part from a basic tutorial example):

[image]

(check [code here](https://gist.github.com/ccamara/7c5eaf82bea91af0c1566efd031f5f6e))

Unfortunately after creating this basic model not only I don't get any results but I get an error "Query overpass API with a string Bad request OverpassAPI". Additionally, I cannot document my model by adding a title, description... so I am asuming I did something wrong. Additionally I guess that my model will only save a file containing points but will not load it to QGIS as I would like to.

Can anyone check my model and/or guide me to achieve such a basic behaviour?

Comment: Can you share what you give in the city field ? You need to provide a query (XML or OQL) to overpass, not just a city.

Comment: Sure! As for the city I am passing a text (defaults to `Zaragoza`) and as for the query I am using this one:https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ccamara/7c5eaf82bea91af0c1566efd031f5f6e/raw/2354f2f8f6996a59c7badbe8248e4ed43b728432/overpass_query . However, if you want to check that or even more, you can always load the file I provided on QGIS-modeler if you have more questions.

Comment: I'm trying on overpass but I got an empty map : http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/h2E, is it normal ?

Comment: I get an empty map, too, but I think that's because Overpass turbo does not check nominatim's boundaries. that's the query with a bbox instead: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/h3h

Comment: @Gustry: your query ...h2E does not have any `out` statement. That's about the only reason, why you get an empty map.

Comment: Oups, mea culpa ! Thanks. I will try to check the problem.

Comment: Is Zaccesibilidad other name of Zaragoza? I attempted to fix query ("test=* in Zaragoza" in overpass wizard, removed test filter with following result: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/uo7 )

Comment: Hello, @MateuszKonieczny: No, Zaccesibilidad is not the name of the city but a keyword used to identify all the commits related to accessibility in Zaragoza.

I honestly don't know what your query is doing, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem with the QGIS Modeller. Could you provide more details, please?

Comment: @ccamara My query downloads all OSM data in Zaragoza (what seems what you want) and fixes query from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200088/download-osm-data-with-quickosm-and-qgis-modeler?noredirect=1#comment304161_200088